# Trying to create a share in win2k8 r2 and getting this error: The local security authority database contains an internal inconsistency

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, network-share

The share used to work for a while, it's a samba share on a remote linux server.
Today I connected to this win server and saw a red X on the share so i've disconnected it and when i'm trying to re-add it by right clicking my computer and choosing "map a network drive" it fails with the error in the topic of the question, it also fails when i do:

```
net use l: \\server\share /user:logsmove
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the solution to this problem in [This thread](https://superuser.com/questions/465900/windows-telling-me-the-local-security-authority-is-internally-inconsistent-upon) , it seems the samba share was not configured correctly.